# How do I get a Broadcom 4318 Wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

My broadcom 4318 card is recognized when lspci is entered in terminal.  It will not work though.  I did a sudo apt-get update then install b43 but nothing.......  any ideas?
Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: please add to your question the output to `sudo lshw -class network` as well as `rfkill list all`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the firmware is missing. Try installing firmware for b43

- Installer package for firmware for the b43 driver

  ```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```